# FileOutputStream only writes the message into the file if I read it between saves

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader, fileoutputstream

I'm trying to write a File read/write class and I made an example activity for this with a button to save to a file I create, a button to read from the file, and a textView to read things from. I tried a few test cases to see if my FileRW worked and it works fine if I read the file after every message but If I try to save multiple messages onto the file without reading between successive tries, only the latest message gets written to the file. I don't know what is causing this behavior.

All the help is appreciated.

```
file = new File(getFilesDir() + "CheckFile.txt");

save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(text.getText().toString().getBytes());
            fos.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});


read.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                textString.append(line);
                textString.append('\n');
            }
            br.close();
            Log.i("Ranai text", textString+"");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: off top: You have some potential issue with resource leak. You must close reader/stream in finally block, don't forget about this. Or use try with resource (in case java7+).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, FileOutputStream will overwrite the contents of the output file when you write to it. By passing the second argument of the constructor as `true`, you can tell the FileOutputStream to append to the existing contents of the file instead of overwriting.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
```

Comment: So text does not get added to the file until I read from it? And whenever I called for, it rewrote the unwritten changes?

Comment: @RanaiSrivastav Basically what happens is first, you open up the FileOutputStream, write some information to it, then you close it. The next time you come around, you opened the FileOutputStream again. However, it wasn't set to append, so instead of adding to the existing contents of the file it just overwrote everything that was in the file. This is why your file only had the latest message - the other ones were overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
```

you want to append to the end of the file rather than write to the beginning